# htaccess AddDefaultCharset not working with PHP files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, utf-8

My server is configured to set the Content-type charse header to "ISO-8859-1" by default, so I was told to create an .htaccess in my root folder with the following, in order to change the charset to UTF-8:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Everything works ok in the root folder, the Content-type is changed, but this won´t work for PHP files, just for HTML.. Why? I've also tried this:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
```

But won't work either..

Comment: Also, my shared server will not allow me to use php_value directives in my htaccess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Just been dealing with this problem

Even though this question is old and probably long forgotten, I found it, someone else may, and so here's my two pennies worth:

According to [apache.org's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset), the stated default is:

> …added to a response if and only if the response's content-type is either **text/plain** or **text/html**

So, first should be to check that the *PHP* output is correctly delivered with a `Content-Type` of `text/html`.

Secondly, make sure that all the files thus being explicitly sent declaring themselves as encoded in *UTF-8*, actually are!
I realise that might be a *"duh"* for most, but still.

As for `AddCharset` failing: **yup!** I have yet to figure out why but,
adding `AddDefaultCharset` and making sure those other considerations were taken care of has worked.

### My guess in the questioner's case...

...if `AddDefaultCharset` wasn't working for *PHP* files, is that they weren't being picked up as outputting `text/html` for some reason, and possibly because of an `AddType` statement in the same or a parent `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to add the following in your `php.ini`:

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```